# Django - create a class instance in AppConfig.ready() only once

Tags: python, django

I need to create a class instance (lets say backend requests session) on the app startup(runserver), and I don't want to rewrite this session after running other management command. How can I achieve this? I tried several approaches and I'm not sure why something like this doesn't work.

```
# app/apps.py
class MyConfig(AppConfig):
    ....
    requests_session = None
    ....
    def ready(self):
        if MyConfig.requests_session is None:
            MyConfig.requests_session = requests.Session()
```

Unfortunately, the condition is always met and the session is recreated. This approach is recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) though.

Other solution for me would be to run MyConfig.ready() only after using selected subset of management commands, is that possible?

Is there completely different better way for me to store requests session?

TIA

Comment: Whatever method you do... this will not work! You may file issue in djangoproject...

Comment: I've seen others mention this didn't work for them. Do you know another solution for my issue please?

Comment: I too tried lot of variations... everything fails...I didn't tried with flagging db and local file system. If you do, likely you will get succeed...

Comment: I think it would work if you used an instance variable instead of a class variable - assuming your code will work with this (it needs to fetch the specific `MyConfig` instance from Django's app registry instead of just `MyConfig.requests_session`.

Comment: @solarissmoke I was thinking about this too, but the problem here is - how to store/access specific MyConfig instance? Global variable will probably work but...

Answer (score 5):

I *think* it should work if you use an instance variable instead of a class variable:

```
# app/apps.py
class MyConfig(AppConfig):

    def __init__(self, app_name, app_module):
        super(MyConfig, self).__init__(app_name, app_module)
        self.requests_session = None

    def ready(self):
        if self.requests_session is None:
            self.requests_session = requests.Session()
```

The question now is how to access this instance variable elsewhere. You can do that like so:

```
from django.apps import apps

# Here myapp is the label of your app - change it as required
# This returns the instance of your app config that was initialised
# at startup.
my_app_config = apps.get_app_config('myapp')

# Use the stored request session
req = my_app_config.requests_session
```

Note that this instance variable only exists in the context of the current process. If you run a management command in a separate process (e.g., `manage.py ...`) then that will create a new instance of each app.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but this is exactly what I'm trying to solve - NOT creating a new instance after running other management command.

Comment: In that case what you are asking doesn't make sense. If you start a new process (e.g., using a management command) then you have to have a new instance of everything. You cannot share instances of objects between processes. The server process and the `manage.py` process are completely unconnected.

Comment: It makes sense when you say it like this, sorry for not being clear enough.. Is there a way to run ready() on some management commands only?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to set an environment variable before calling the management command, and checking for that environment variable in the `ready()` method to decide whether to do something.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help