# Store object for later in django app's `ready`

Tags: python, django, pubnub

I have a Django project that includes an app with a `ready` method. I use the ready method to create a Pubnub listener object. The code looks something like this:

```
# myproject/myapp/apps.py
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
from django.apps import AppConfig
from somewhere import SomeNamespace


class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
    def message(self, pubnub, message):
        # store the message in the database

class MyPubnub(PubNub):
    def __init__(self):
        pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
        pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'demo'
        pnconfig.publish_key = 'demo'
        super(MyPubnub, self).__init__(config=pnconfig)

        self.add_listener(MySubscribeCallback())
        self.subscribe().channels('demo').execute()

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    def ready(self):
        SomeNamespace.my_pubnub_listener = MyPubnub()
```

Where is the appropriate namespace to store `my_pubnub_listener`? Will it get cleaned up after startup if I just put it in `self.my_pubnub_listener`? Is there a better place for it?

Comment: What did you end up doing? Did it work?  Is this a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593444/django-create-a-class-instance-in-appconfig-ready-only-once?

Answer (score -1):

To define a cron job, store and expose the object called `background_scheduler` (like `MySubscribeCallback`) :

```py
# django/myapp/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger


class MyPubnubConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'mypubnub'

    def __init__(self, app_name, app_module):
        super(MyPubnubConfig, self).__init__(app_name, app_module)
        self.my_pubnub_listener  = None

    def ready(self):
        if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true':
            return
        if self.my_pubnub_listener is None:
            background_scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
            background_scheduler.add_job(task1, CronTrigger.from_crontab('* * * * *')) # Every minutes (debug).
            background_scheduler.start()
            return background_scheduler

    def task1(self):
        print("cron task is working")
```

You can then call it later:

```py
# api.py
from django.apps import apps

@router.get("/background-task")
def background_task(request):
    """
        Run a background task.
    """
    user = request.user
    mypubnub_config= apps.get_app_config('mypubnub')
    background_scheduler = mypubnub_config.background_scheduler
    return {"status": "Success", "True": str(background_scheduler)}
```