# How to manage session with 3rd party API in Django?

Tags: python, django, rest, http, session

Context:
I have a Django based application. This application has various REST API endpoints where users can gather data. Some of this data needs to be pulled from a third-party API. This external API uses basic authentication.

In order to fetch this data, I have the following code implemented in my endpoint logic.

```
    def metadata(jira_key: str, format=None):
        username = "example"
        password = "example"
        try:
            print(f"fetching {jira_key} with '{username}' credentials")
            url = f"https://external.api.com/issue/{jira_key}"
            session = requests.Session()
            session.auth = username, password
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            response = session.get(
                url, headers=headers)
            print(f"response: {response.status_code}")
            return response

        except Exception as e:
            message = {"error": "Uncaught error", "message": str(e)}
            return message
```

Long story short; it works! This endpoint is essentially just a proxy for another API. This is done for security purposes.

However, I have been experiencing lock-outs where permission for the service account needs to be reinstated periodically...

I suspect the session is being generated every time the endpoint is hit.

So my question is this:
How can I implement a persisted request.Session() with basic auth that is established at build time, and reused for each requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608883/6523756), namely instantiate your session in the `ready` function of the app config class, which is run only once when starting django and then stored in the application memory.